# How to upgrade PowerShell version from 2.0 to 3.0?

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, error-handling, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I write "Add-migration Initial" in Package Manager Console window in Visual Studio 2015 and it says:

> EF Core commands do not support PowerShell version 2.0. Please upgrade PowerShell to 3.0 or greater and restart Visual Studio.

I expected to be created a folder Migrations contains the database.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download and install the Windows Management Framework. Version 3.0 can be found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595; version 4.0 can be found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855; and version 5.1 can be found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616.

Comment: Yes - PowerShell is integrated with and strongly dependent on the Windows Management Framework. You don't need to install all three versions, however; installing the latest (5.1) will give you all the capabilities of the earlier versions.